# Writing Selenium python xpath code (beginner)

Tags: python, list, selenium-webdriver, xpath

To preface, I'm completely new to world of coding. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Goal
Use selenium to scrap website every 10 min and look for updated changes. I would like to eventually scrap the website every 10 minute and see if there were any previous changes made.
The website I'm trying to scrap carries ranking of TV models that gets updated.

Issue
After logging into the website and inspecting the models, I'm able to find element with commonalities that has the model names. Below is code block for the first 3 highest ranking models.
1st model: LG OLED77C3PUA
2nd model: LG OLED77C3PUA
3rd model: LG OLED77C3AUA

p class="crux-product-title crux-product-title--small classic-view__brand-and-model">

LG OLED77G2PUA

...
p class="crux-product-title crux-product-title--small classic-view__brand-and-model">

LG OLED77C3PUA

...
p class="crux-product-title crux-product-title--small classic-view__brand-and-model">
LG OLED77C3AUA

Commonality seems to be p class="crux-product-title crux-product-title--small classic-view__brand-and-model">.

I'm not quite sure how to create an xpath following it. Following is what I have so far.
I'm not sure if I wrote the last line of code correctly (for By.Xpath). I also get following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
for p in range(len(model)):
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

I'm not quite sure about next step. If anyone could point to the right direction, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

I was hoping that it would be able to create a list of all the model names according to the element specified.

Comment: Show us your code.  It looks like you used an API that returns a simple item, whereas you expected an API that returns several items.  Selenium has both (for example, `find_element` vs `find_elements`).

Comment: Please, take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As you say you are "completely new to world of coding", SO is not the best medium to learn "everything". Have a look at the [tour]. Also possibly worth reading: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3124333)

Comment: I assume you want to do something like `for element in webdriver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'crux-product-title crux-product-title--small classic-view__brand-and-model'):`

Comment: Selenium is not the best choice for data scraping, use bs4 or scrapy for that, especially if you want to check the data every 10 minutes

Comment: Welcome, as of now it seems that you are looking for sources of information. For clear interactive step-by-step tutorials (for free) i suggest you have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/  and just start with python. Then you could have a look at selenium etc. Take your time, understanding each step of your code will be key to make a steady progress. Ignore all the "get certified" stuff, it is really unneccesary.